# Boundary Callback (Android Paging Library) with CoroutineScope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, android-viewmodel, android-paging

I'm trying to implement `Android Paging library` with `ViewModel` and `Kotlin Coroutines`

I have a `ViewModel` that implements `CoroutineScope`. It depends on `Repository`:

```
class MovieListViewModel(
    private val movieRepository: MovieRepository
) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.IO

    private lateinit var _movies: LiveData<PagedList<MovieBrief>>

    val movies: LiveData<PagedList<MovieBrief>>
        get() = _movies

    init {
        launch {
            _movies = LivePagedListBuilder(movieRepository.getMovies(), DATABASE_PER_PAGE)
                .setBoundaryCallback(movieRepository.movieBoundaryCallback)
                .build()
        }
    }

}
```

And This is my `Repository`. I inject the `BoundaryCallback` with `Kodein` Dependecy Injector.

```
class MovieRepositoryImpl(
    private val movieDao: MovieDao,
    boundaryCallback: MovieBoundaryCallback
) : MovieRepository {

    override suspend fun getMovies(): DataSource.Factory<Int, MovieBrief> {
        return movieDao.getMovies()
    }

    override val movieBoundaryCallback = boundaryCallback

}
```

Inside `BoundaryCallback` class The `onItemAtEndLoaded` calls the RESTAPI and then saves the data to Room database (both are suspending functions). So I have to access my ViewModel's coroutine scope. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: have you found any solution to that? i am not satisfied with my current one

Comment: @NoushadHasan not till now, need to pass the scope via method/constructor injection

Comment: Your repository should not get the coroutine scope to do its work (since it's someone else's scope, why would it?).  I think your problem arises because you are using different paradigms to fetch your data: cooroutines and callback. I recommend using suspendCoroutine (or `suspendCancelableCoroutine` to convert your callback provider to provide a suspend function, so you can easily use it in your view model.

Comment: @AdibFaramarzi can u explain more? I didn't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Paging library** ***version 3*** is now available and supports `Coroutine`.
`PagedList.BoundaryCallback` is now `Deprecated` and for this case we need to use `RemoteMediator` and it has a `suspend fun load` for handling `Remote+Local` pagination